# Calculation of $y' + y\tan x = \sec x $ with Lagrange method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is:

$$y' + y\tan x = \sec x \tag{1}$$

I am using Lagrange method here. so:

---

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -y\tan x$$

$$-\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int \tan x \, dx$$

$$ y = C \cdot\cos x$$

put $C$ as a $x$ dependent and finding its derivative I have:

$$y(x) = C(x) \cdot \cos x$$

$$y'(x) = C'(x) \cos x - C(x)\sin x$$

---

substituting $y(x)$ and $y'(x)$ into $(1)$:

$$C'(x) \cos x - C(x) \sin x + C(x)\cos x \tan x = \sec x$$

with this step something always have to be reduced, but I do not see what can be reduced here, am I wrong then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C(x)\cos x\tan x=C(x)\sin x\implies C'(x)\cos x=\sec x\implies C'(x)=\sec^2 x$$So$$C(x)=\tan x+k$$

---

This gives a general solution of $y=\sin x+k\cos x$. Substituting in to the original equation: $$\cos x-k\sin x+\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos x}+k\sin x=\sec x\\\frac{\cos^2 x+\sin^2x}{\cos x}=\sec x$$ which is consistent.

Comment: Seems I've just forgotten proper formula, thank you very much (not that I remember each of them :/)